# CSS Float not wrapping around

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="block pink float"></div>
<div class="block blue float"></div>
<div class="block green"></div>
<div class="block orange"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .block {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .float { float: left; }
    .pink { background: #ee3e64; }
    .blue { background: #44accf; }
    .green { background: #b7d84b; }
    .orange { background: #E2A741; }
```

Why is the orange and green boxes not wrapping and instead appearing underneath? According to my understanding if there is enough space the elements will surround the float and move underneath it, not behind it.

I am aware of the clearfix solution of `<div style="clear: both"></div>` but do not understand why the above is happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/ap5ugv8s/

I would've expected the above from an absolutely positioned element, not a float.

Answer (score 3):

That's because blocks with `overflow: visible` that follow a float behave like this:

[image]

To fix it, you can set `overflow: hidden`. Then it will behave like this:

[image]

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.float { float: left; }
.pink { background: #ee3e64; }
.blue { background: #44accf; }
.green { background: #b7d84b; }
.orange { background: #E2A741; }
```

```html
<div class="block pink float"></div>
<div class="block blue float"></div>
<div class="block green"></div>
<div class="block orange"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I still don't understand how I am getting the result.

Comment: @RobertRocha If you have `overflow: visible`, the `width` starts counting at the left of the floated element. If you have `overflow: hidden`, it starts at its right. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ap5ugv8s/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can word this correctly. Floated elements, as you know, are not in the normal flow. While floated elements will line up against each other, to other block elements it's as if they aren't there at all. This means they will be placed over the floated elements **if they are not positioned**, such as `position:relative;`. You can try adding that to some of your non-floated divs to play with and see how adding positioning changes things. Positioning of the elements is the key phrase.

I may edit this some more in the morning when I wake up but you may want to read [the W3C's explanation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#floats) in the spec.

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist.

Comment: Ok ok im getting closer to enlightenment

Answer (score 0):

Not if it is a `block`. What is happening is floats are collapsing on top of block elements. And blocks stack on top of each other. I would use `inline-block` instead to get the wrapping with floats.

```
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ap5ugv8s/2/

Comment: The float causes the natively block element `<div>` to go out of normal flow and move the the right or left as far as possible it would not make sense to tell the browser make me block again.